# UIPicker View Rotate Support

Tags: xcode, rotation, uipickerview

I have a universal iOS 6 Application that supports both landscape and portrait orientations.

I have a view that consists of a UIPickerView at the bottom and a label near the top.

On an iPad or iPad Mini there's enough space for the UIPickerView to rotate. However the UIPickerView consumes the entire screen area on an iPhone (both 4 inch and 3.5 inch screens).

I'm sure it doesn't help I have a Tab Bar at the bottom.

[image: Example image]

Is there anyway I could EITHER shorten/shrink my UIPickerView or force portrait-only in this view?

Answer (score 0):

You can force portrait-only through a combination of `-[UIViewController supportedInterfaceRotations]` and `-[UIViewController shouldAutorotate]`. (This is slightly different in iOS 5 and lower, where you have to use `-[UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:]`.

Comment: returned "false" for shouldAutoRotate and returned "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait" for supportedInferfaceOrientations. Didn't work :(